# Excel spreadsheet - column resize

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am unable to resize the Excel column width using my mouse. This function stopped out of the blue - I was able to resize the same spreadsheet I was working on a few minutes prior to the issue. I closed it and went into another spreadsheet with the same result. It seems I have changed a setting that applies to any and all spreadsheets. I have right clicked the cell, clicked on Format, and clicked the 'Lock' button, with no success. There are no hidden columns or rows.

Could I have changed a setting or do you have any ideas to share, other than what I have already tried? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally one finds this when the worksheet/workbook is protected or the column is locked double check by right clicking on the column and formatting cells.

If it does it in all other worksheets even new ones try to reset your settings by trying to repair it.

To repair it go to control panel programs find office click change and then select repair.

Comment: Thank you. What is occurring now is the cursor seems to be off one character. For example, when I filter data I now need to move my mouse further to the right to "capture" the selection.Any ideas?